# I have a question about getting speific field from a record stored in lowdb

Tags: javascript

How do I retrieve a specific field from a record in lowdb?
let's say, I have a lowdb database name 'account with the following record:

```
"account": [
 {
 "name": "bill",
 "email": "bill@gmail.com",
 "balance": "500",
 }
]
```

I only want to return the value of balance on the screen. I am using javascript as front-end.

When I sue the command below, it returns the complete record, but I only want a specific field:

```
console.log(db.get('account').find({email: 'bill@gmail.com'}).value());
```

Comment: what about console.log(db.get('account').find({email: 'bill@gmail.com'}).value().balance);

Comment: Thanks, << console.log(db.get('account').find({email: 'bill@gmail.com'}).value().balance); >> worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that in lowdb directly with:

```
console.log(db.get('account.balance').find({email: 'bill@gmail.com'}).value());
```

This is possible because `lowdb` gives you access to all the `loadash` api, and that way of calling `get` is given by loadash:

[loadash get method](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get)

Or simply access that prop in JS from the returning obj:

```
console.log(db.get('account').find({email: 'bill@gmail.com'}).value().balance);
```

Comment: Thanks, << console.log(db.get('account').find({email: 'bill@gmail.com'}).value().balance); >> worked!

Comment: can you try also `console.log(db.get('account.balance').find({email: 'bill@gmail.com'}).value());` ? that should work too, you are using the `loadash get` selector

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you receive an array of records - with only a single element in it - you can modify your statement to

```
console.log(db.get('account').find({email: 'bill@gmail.com'}).value()[0].balance);
```

Comment: Thanks, << console.log(db.get('account').find({email: 'bill@gmail.com'}).value().balance); >> worked!